# can't connect to solr server

Tags: solrnet

We have a linux box set up with the Solr server and a co-worker wrote a java program to interface with it for searching.  I've been asked to do the same but with .net for another product of ours so I downloaded the docs and sample files from [google solrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/). I updated the web.config file's solrUrl key to the address of the existing solr server (http://192.168.10.26:8983/solr) in hopes that I can start testing against a server that's already set up and configured.  However when I run the sample app I get the following error.

> Couldn't connect to Solr. Please make sure that Solr is running on 'http://192.168.10.26:8983/solr/alex/admin' or change the address in your web.config, then restart the application.

Unfortunately the other programmer doesn't have any idea what I should try, soooo, anyone here have any ideas?  Does something on the linux server need to be set up for the .net client?  Or???  Thanks.

Comment: can u surf to it from a web browser?

Comment: yes.  And sorry, the error I pasted in wasn't the latest error.  I had tried a different url in the config which resulted in the error I posted but, even with the correct url - http://192.168.10.26:8983/solr it's still giving me the same error message.